# How to zero fill a number inside of an Excel cell

Tags: excel, formatting, worksheet-function

How do you zero fill a number to 10 positions inside an excel spreadsheet?

i.e. If cell A1 has 1234 how can cell A2 display 0000001234 (10 postions).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

=TEXT(A1,"0000000000")

Comment: The disadvantage of this method is that the number itself can no longer be used in other formulae.

Comment: Sure it can, just use VALUE(A1) instead of A1 in the other formulas.

Comment: True, but it then means you have to change all cells refering to A1.  Much easier to use mavnn's answer below, to be honest.

Comment: Depends what you want: I've seen a lot of people get very confused when formatting disguises the actual value in a cell (which is what my solution does, in effect). I actually marked up Alison's solution as ihmo it's more useful in more situations that simply changing the format.

Comment: I've just gotten in the habit of always using VALUE when I want a number since it's shockingly common to get a spreadsheet that has a number formatted as text on row 4934 and there's no way to be able to tell without examining every cell your formula applies to.

Comment: Obviously if you work with spreadsheets only touched by yourself you can throw caution to the wind.

Answer (score 16):

Not a programming question, really:

1. Select cells you want formatted in this way.
2. Right click and select "Format Cells..."
3. Select the "Number" Tag, and scroll down to "Custom" in the category list.
4. Type "0000000000" into the Type field.

Answer (score 5):

Format>Cells...>Number>Custom>Type>0000000000

Comment: I don't see a 'Special' option under Number in Excel 2003.

Comment: Fixed the typo.  I meant 'Custom', not 'Special'.  Though in my copy of Excel 2003, both are present.

Answer (score 4):

This formula is variable.

It checks the length of the value and add "0" in front

Now the lenght is 10. You can change it.

```
=REPT("0",10-LEN(A1))&A1
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a pretty old post, but I've just came across the same problem while exporting a sql table to excel, and I found I very simple solution!
Just set the cell format to ' Custom' then type the amount of characters you want the final number to have;
In your case 10 positions '0000000000'
I don't usually reply to the stackoverflow's posts, so I don't have enought reputation to post images;

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following.

```
right( "0000000000" & number, 10 )
```

Put 10 zeroes on the left, take the right-most 10 positions, whatever they turn out to be.

Also, you have

```
text( number, "0000000000" )
```

Comment: right("0000000000"&number,10) works poorly for negative numbers.

Answer (score -2):

How to display full the number inside in excel workseet?

I.e cell A1 "2.40252E+13" how to display full number in A1 became "24025207702012"